# Tensorflow model with multuple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have the following neural net model. I have an input to as int sequence. And there is also another two neural nets beginning from same type of input layer and get concatenated together. This concatenation is the final output of the model. If I specified the input of the model as `main_input` and the `entity_extraction` and `relation_extraction` networks also start with main_input and their output is the final output, then does it mean that I have 3 inputs to this model? What is the underlying input/output mechanism in this model?

```
main_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='int32', name='main_input')

x = embedding_layer(main_input)
x = CuDNNLSTM(KG_EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Avg(x)
x = Dense(KG_EMBEDDING_DIM)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
# relation_extraction = Reshape([KG_EMBEDDING_DIM])(x)
relation_extraction = Transpose(x)

x = embedding_layer(main_input)
x = CuDNNLSTM(KG_EMBEDDING_DIM, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Avg(x)
x = Dense(KG_EMBEDDING_DIM)(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
# entity_extraction = Reshape([KG_EMBEDDING_DIM])(x)
entity_extraction = Transpose(x)

final_output = Dense(units=20, activation='softmax')(Concatenate(axis=0)([entity_extraction,relation_extraction]))

m = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[final_output])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`main_input` is the only input into this model. `relation_extraction` and `embedding_layer` both use the same input. The output of these two LSTM layers are transposed, concatenated, and passed through a `Dense` layer to produce the final output.